# System и кодировка в R

Tags: windows, кодировка, r

Пытаюсь собрать данные по всем задачам в планировщике windows.

Для этого использую

```
cmd <- sprintf("schtasks /Query /FO CSV /V")
x <- system(cmd, intern = TRUE)
```

Получаю файл в строку в неопределенной кодировке

```
x[1]
[1] "\"€¬п г§« \",\"€¬п § ¤ зЁ\",\"‚аҐ¬п б«Ґ¤гойҐЈ® § ЇгбЄ \",\"‘®бв®п­ЁҐ\",\"ђҐ¦Ё¬ ўе®¤  ў бЁбвҐ¬г\",\"‚аҐ¬п Їа®и«®Ј® § ЇгбЄ \",\"Џа®и«л© аҐ§г«мв в\",\"Ђўв®а\",\"‡ ¤ з  ¤«п ўлЇ®«­Ґ­Ёп\",\"ђ Ў®з п Ї ЇЄ \",\"ЏаЁ¬Ґз ­ЁҐ\",\"‘®бв®п­ЁҐ ­ §­ зҐ­­®© § ¤ зЁ\",\"‚аҐ¬п Їа®бв®п\",\"“Їа ў«Ґ­ЁҐ н«ҐЄва®ЇЁв ­ЁҐ¬\",\"‡ ЇгбЄ ®в Ё¬Ґ­Ё\",\"“¤ «Ёвм § ¤ зг, Ґб«Ё ®­  ­Ґ ЇҐаҐ­ҐбҐ­ \",\"Ћбв ­®ўЁвм § ¤ зг, Ґб«Ё ®­  ўлЇ®«­пҐвбп X з Ё X ¬Ё­\",\"ђ бЇЁб ­ЁҐ\",\"’ЁЇ а бЇЁб ­Ёп\",\"‚аҐ¬п ­ з « \",\"„ в  ­ з « \",\"„ в  ®Є®­з ­Ёп\",\"¤­.\",\"¬Ґб.\",\"Џ®ўв®апвм: Є ¦¤лҐ\",\"Џ®ўв®апвм: ¤®: ўаҐ¬п\",\"Џ®ўв®апвм: ў вҐзҐ­ЁҐ: ¤«ЁвҐ«м­®бвм\",\"Џ®ўв®апвм: ®бв ­®ўЁвм, Ґб«Ё ўлЇ®«­пҐвбп\""
```

что должно быть :

```
"Имя узла","Имя задачи","Время следующего запуска","Состояние","Режим входа в систему","Время прошлого запуска","Прошлый результат","Автор","Задача для выполнения","Рабочая папка","Примечание","Состояние назначенной задачи","Время простоя","Управление электропитанием","Запуск от имени","Удалить задачу, если она не перенесена","Остановить задачу, если она выполняется X ч и X мин","Расписание","Тип расписания","Время начала","Дата начала","Дата окончания","дн.","мес.","Повторять: каждые","Повторять: до: время","Повторять: в течение: длительность","Повторять: остановить, если выполняется"
```

Пробовал различные варианты iconv и запись и чтение файлов(write.lines,write.csv,write.csv2 +  encoding) в различной кодировке - ничего не помогло.

Если сохранить данные в csv и затем через notepad++ конвертировать в utf-8 работает верно. Но хотелось бы исключить ручную конвертацию в notepad++

## Доп инфо

```
> Encoding(x[1])
[1] "unknown"

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251  LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251    LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x <- iconv(x, from = "CP866", to = "windows-1251")
```

Comment: Как вы поняли , что это именно "CP866"? я перебрал множество вариантов , но к этому не пришел

Comment: Дык, из DOS же строка приходит :)